# Calling a PHP function within an <a > tag, anchor tag

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to call a PHP  function within an anchor tag. I have a PHP function called `logout();`

Now I want something similar to this.

```
<a href="logout();" >Logout</a>
```

I know with Javascript this works but what is the best approach using PHP function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No; PHP is a [server side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), so it is inaccessible to the HTML like this. JavaScript can do this, as it is a [client-side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting).

Since PHP is a server side language, a message (in the form of an HTTP request) must be sent to the server from the browser (the client) for any PHP to be executed - including your PHP function `logout`.

You have a few options...

### Option 1

Follow the hyperlink to a script which executes the `logout()` function...

HTML

```
<a href="theLogOutScript.php">Logout</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php
   // ...
   logout();
   // ...
?>
```

### Option 2

Submit a form to a script which executes the `logout()` function...

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="theLogOutScript.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

### Option 3

Use an `XMLHttpRequest`/AJAX request to communicate with the server. (no sample code provided)

Comment: [Richard JP Le Guen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/248129/richard-jp-le-guen) , in **Option 1** is it possible only calling only a function in PHP file instead of calling a PHP file?

Comment: @MalusJan No. If you'll do that, it will automatically process the function without clicking the logout button or link.

Answer (score 8):

No, in order to call PHP you will have to make a request back to the server. You will either need to link to another PHP page:

```
<a href="/logout" >Logout</a>
```

Or you will have to make a JavaScript AJAX call to a PHP page ("web service") that will perform the logout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href ='logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ...... your code....      
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

You didn't specify the format of your document. If your document format is **HTML** you'll need to load an external file but if it's **.php** You can do it by setting your function inside a variable like so:

```
<?php $myLogout  = logout();?>
<a href="<?php echo $myLogout; ?>">Logout</a>
```

Comment: What?  Did you even read the other answers?  This is entirely incorrect.

Comment: @dimo414 I've been using this code for years (mostly on wordpress sites) but as you say I could be incorrect, If you could elaborate on why my answer is wrong i'll be happy to read and learn something new.

Comment: OP is asking how to call a PHP function when a user clicks a link, the same way one would do with JavaScript.  The answer, as every other poster has said, is this is not possible because PHP is a server side language.  You can of course put the *result* of a method call in an an `<a href="...">` (or anywhere else on the page), but that is not the question.

Comment: I see, i misunderstood the question, totally agree thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This code will automatically process the function without clicking the logout button or link. But it may produce different scenario depending on how the `logout()` function work.