# restart session in PHP page using HTML <form action method=GET>

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to call the function `session_destroy()` and print a string without success. I tried to follow this post [calling-a-php-function-within-an-a-tag-anchor-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782208/calling-a-php-function-within-an-a-tag-anchor-tag) and redirect to a different page, but I get the error

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Obviously if I go to another page there is no session initialized to be destroyed. I suppose that I should use a function like

```
function restartSession{
  session_destroy();
  print "SESSION has been destroyed - all session data deleted";
}
```

and use `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">` , but how do I do that by using one single php file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal anchor tag for `GET`:

```
<a href="http://localhost/lab5.php?restartSession=true">restart Session</a>
```

Then you can put this into your index.php as well:

```
if(isset($_GET["restartSession"])){
  restartSession();
}

function restartSession(){
  if(session_id() == '') {     //check if Session already exists
    print "Only start Session"; 
    session_start();
  }
  else {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    print "Session restarted";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works for restarting the counter! but the session ID remains the same and "Session Started" gets appended to the session ID and the information in the screenshot2 remains the same and I cannot display the information as in screenshot3. any other idea?

Comment: @sirio where did you place the code? Put it on top and add a <br> to the output in order to separate the lines from each other

Comment: if i do that I get Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() and then all the previous code. The page should display only the code in screenshot 3, not just having it separated.

Comment: @sirio you can put the HTML which should be shown in an other case in the if brackets

Comment: and as the URL says action=restartSession I believe that <form action method=GET> should be used to call the function

Comment: <form action method=GET> does the same as a link with ?action=restartSession at the end

Answer (score 1):

I don't see code of your **lab5destroy.php** file, but I suppose that this code is from that page:

```
function restartSession{
  session_destroy();
  print "SESSION has been destroyed - all session data deleted";
}
```

If so, you have to init sessions before session destroy:

```
function restartSession{
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
  print "SESSION has been destroyed - all session data deleted";
}
```

If you want to destroy session on one page, you don't neet to use form.
You just update your link:

```
<a href="http://localhost/lab5.php?restart=1">restart session</a>
```

And on top of your **lab5.php** you just insert this code:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_GET['restart'])) {
      session_start();
      session_destroy();
      header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'lab5.php');
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My option: make a head.php file with `session_start();` in it what's in the src folder and on the top of every page include it:

```
<?php include "src/head.php"; ?>
```

Later on your project you can put mysql connect's, style.css's, and other things what you want to include on every page.